# Can we do YouTube live stream embedded inside a react-native application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, youtube-api

I want to create an application in react-native that support live streaming. I am using `react-native-youtube` library to enable youtube feature inside my application. I know i can stream the live video using this library, but how can i create live stream event from the application.

I want to create a publisher and subscriber scenario where publisher (with admin privileges) starts a live stream directly from the application broadcast to all normal user via push notification that a live streams has started and the subscribers can view the stream either on application or on youtube channel.

Comment: So what's your question? If you can do it in a regular application, then you can also do it in a react application.

Comment: the official docs has example on java and android only, i dont event know if i can do it on swift

Comment: Have you found any proper solution for this ? I also want same functionality.